# Как сделать столбец TEXT уникальным в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `table` в MySQL.
Как сделать столбец `des` уникальным, учитывая что его тип - `TEXT`?
Туда планирую вставлять тексты длиной больше 1000 символов\

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать через phpmyAmdin, но не получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вставке текста буду писать такой запрос, чтобы он пропускал дублирующие тексты:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table...
```

Но для этого нужен столбец des уникальный

Comment: так лучше не делать.

Comment: В этом нет смысла

Comment: Связанные вопросы и ответы на англоязычной версии SO: [тыц1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033378/make-text-column-as-unique-key), [тыц2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698884/mysql-unique-text-field-using-additional-hash-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоретически - создать уникальный индекс. Поскольку без указания длины индексируемого префикса поле типа TEXT индексировать нельзя - указать заведомо больше (стараясь не вылететь за пределы размера индекса).

Но я бы предложил создать вычисляемое поле хэша этого текстового поля, и вот именно по нему уже создавать уникальный индекс. При правильном выборе алгоритма хэширования вероятность коллизии исчезающе мала.

Comment: неужели в 21 веке нельзя добавить в бд mysql текст и дать ему уникальность среди остальных элементов

Comment: @Евгений, можно, вот только потом разработчики вроде вас начнут бомбардировать support запросами - почему когда я вставляю картинки или видео в TEXT поле (например закодированное как base64) - БД встает колом? :-D Ключи и другие "constraints" в БД должны работать  максимально быстро.

Comment: @Евгений Можно. И мой ответ рассказывает, как именно это сделать. Другой вопрос - если потребовалась уникальность в общем произвольного, неформализованного, текста, значит, в архитектуре БД есть серьёзные ошибки. И надо не спрашивать, как его обуникалить, а возвращаться назад и переделывать всё заново, начиная с анализа предметной области.